# Laravel - Composer can't find config file

Tags: git, laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel project which I created and uploaded to github.

On a second computer, I have installed composer which works in cmd, and I have downloaded the project files through git. The idea is to be able to use git, and be able to work on the same project on either computer.

But for example when trying to do

```
   composer show illuminate/database
```

or

```
composer install
```

I get this message:

```
"Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin"
"To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file"
```

Also when doing

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get

```
Warning: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\workspace\myproject\bootstrap../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR' in 'C:\workspace\myproject\bootstrap\autoload.php' on line 17 )
```

In my .gitignore file I saw that "\vendor" was added, so that folder is missing. If I edit the "autoload.php" file on line 17, from: `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

to:    `require __DIR__.'\autoload.php';`

I get many lines with this error:

```
constant LARAVEL_START already defined
```

I think "composer install" would add the "vendor" folder, if the config error could be fixed.

This is the .gitignore file, by the way:

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
.tmp
.sass-cache
/vendor
Homestead.yaml
Homestead.json
.env
```

`"C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin"` is added as an environment variable, and if I remove it, the "composer" command doesn't work.

It seems that there are some steps needed before this will work, can you see what the problem is?

Comment: Are you running `composer install` or `composer update` from Laravel project's folder?

Comment: "composer install", maybe I should try "composer update"? (edit - it shows the same error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin means that you have a COMPOSER environment variable defined and set to C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin. You should unset/delete that env var.

Comment: But then the "composer" command stops working in cmd. I think this variable was added when I installed composer. And it appears to be correct - the composer files are there (composer, composer.bat and composer.phar)

Comment: It did work today, when I deleted the environment variable from "system variables " PLUS from "user variables". Only when I deleted both of them, it worked (I only deleted system variable first). On my other computer however it seems to work despite the env-variable..